# Identify kernel module which created a sysfs entry

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

On a running Linux system, I want to know which device driver module created a particular sysfs entry. Is it possible to know? I know I can grep for relevant strings in the kernel source and try to identify. But, is there a way without doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You can find which driver has created a sysfs entry by going through its source. If the driver uses **device_create_file()/device_remove_file()** in its init/exit sequences respectively then you can be sure a sysfs attribute file has been created by the driver.
You can also find **DEVICE_ATTR(_name, _mode, _show, _store)** macro in the source to find out what functionality is provided by the sysfs file.
Usually you can either cat the file or echo a string to it.
A **cat /sys/.../file**, will correspond to the _show function and an **echo /sys/.../file** will correspond to the _store function mentioned in the macro.

Comment: Thanks sanrio for the reply. I knew about the thing you have mentioned. My question is, given a sysfs entry, is it possible to tell to which driver module(if listed by lsmod) it belongs to on a running Linux system.

Comment: i doubt there is a direct way to do that.. If you do come across one then please share it here :)